# Computation of the genus of a curve, containing in a singular quadric

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a smooth rational curve of degree $4$, which is contained in the singular quadric $V(z_0^2+z_1^2+z_2^2)\subset \mathbb{P}_3$. What I want to prove is that it is impossible. There is the so called adjunction formula, which can be used to compute the genus of such a curve, and the evaluation gives the value $g=1$ (and that is what we need - a contradiction, because in our case $g=0$ because of rationality). The problem is that the adjunction formula does not work for singlular surfaces. How can I improve the proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you blow up the origin and compute the genus of the strict transform?